# UTF-8 encoding for xhtml2pdf in Django / media URI must start with /static/ or /media/

Tags: django, encoding, xhtml2pdf, pisa

I am using xhtml2pdf package to generate a pdf file from an html template in my django application. The pdf file generates correctly (no errors), however, I have encountered a problem with UTF-8 encoding. My generated pdf file, instead of special charactes (PL language), shows black squares. I have gone through almost all solutions available online, but none of them helped. When I am using ReportLab and generate pdf without a template, all seems to be okay.
Am I missing something perhaps on the views side?

To update, I believe the problem I have is really in retrieving the font.
I have added the callback_link, and tried to used {% static %} reference in my template. But this throws an error ***media URI must start with /static/ or /media/***

**My html template**

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>PDF {{obj.orderNumber}}</title>
    <style>

        

        @font-face {
            font-family: "Roboto-Black";
            src: url({% static "fonts/Roboto.ttf" %});
        }
        @font-face {
            font-family: "Roboto-Regular";
            src: url({% static "Roboto-Regular.ttf" %});
        }
        @font-face {
            font-family: "Roboto-Bold";
            src: url({% static "Roboto-Bold.ttf" %});
            font-weight: bold;
        }

           
            body, html  {
            font-family: Roboto;
    
           }

        
        table { -pdf-keep-with-next: true; }
        p { margin: 0; -pdf-keep-with-next: true; }
        p.separator { -pdf-keep-with-next: false; font-size: 6pt; }
 
        .bander{
            color:brown; 
            font-size:13pt;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <img src="media/logo.jpg" style="height:60px;">
    <h2> PLAN ROZKROJU ZLECENIA: </h2>
    <h1 style="color:#997207;">{{obj.orderNumber}} {{obj.orderName}}</h3>
        <h2> Naklad: {{obj.orderQuantity}} szt </h2>
        <h4> Data utworzenia wydruku: {{obj3}} </h4>
        
        <div>
            <table class="table table-bordered" style="text-align: center; padding: 5px;" border="0.2">
                <thead class="table-active">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Nazwa materialu</th>
                        <th scope="col">Ilosc</th>
                        <th scope="col">Nazwa czesci</th>
                        <th scope="col">Wymiar (mm)</th>
                        <th scope="col">Wymiar 2 (mm)</th>
                        
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    {% for item in obj2 %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ item.itemMaterial }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.itemQuantity }} szt</td>
                        <td>{{ item.itemName }}</td>
                        {% if item.itemBander == 'OKLEJANIE 1 STR' %}
                            <td class="text-center"><b class="bander">*</b> {{ item.itemDimmension1 }}</td>
                        {% elif item.itemBander == 'OKLEJANIE 2 STR' %}
                            <td class="text-center"><b class="bander">*</b> {{ item.itemDimmension1 }} <b class="bander">*</b></td>
                        {% else %}
                            <td class="text-center">{{ item.itemDimmension1 }}</td>
                        {% endif %}

                         {% if item.itemBander2 == 'OKLEJANIE 1 STR' %}
                            <td class="text-center"><b class="bander">*</b> {{ item.itemDimmension2 }}</td>
                        {% elif item.itemBander2 == 'OKLEJANIE 2 STR' %}
                            <td class="text-center"><b class="bander">*</b> {{ item.itemDimmension2 }} <b class="bander">*</b></td>
                        {% else %}
                            <td class="text-center">{{ item.itemDimmension2 }}</td>
                        {% endif %}

                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <p></p>
        <h6><i> LEGENDA:<b class="bander">*</b> wymiar - oklejanie 1-str // <b class="bander">*</b> wymiar <b class="bander">*</b> - oklejanie 2 str</i></h6>
            
</body>

</html>
```

**My views.py**

```
def link_callback(uri, rel):
    """
    Convert HTML URIs to absolute system paths so xhtml2pdf can access those
    resources
    """

    sUrl = settings.STATIC_URL            # Typically /static/
    sRoot = settings.STATIC_ROOT          # Typically /home/userX/project_static/
    mUrl = settings.MEDIA_URL             # Typically /media/
    mRoot = settings.MEDIA_ROOT           # Typically /home/userX/project_static/media/
    bRoot = settings.BASE_DIR             # Project's base directory

    if uri.startswith(mUrl):
        path = os.path.join(mRoot, uri.replace(mUrl, ""))
    elif uri.startswith(sUrl):
        path = os.path.join(sRoot, uri.replace(sUrl, ""))
    else:
        return os.path.join(bRoot, '../', uri)

    # make sure that file exists
    if not os.path.isfile(path):
        raise Exception(
            'media URI must start with %s or %s' % (sUrl, mUrl)
        )
    return path
# PDF VIEWS#
@login_required
@admin_or_manager_required
def render_pdf_view(request, pk):
    template_path = "orders/pdf.html"
    obj = get_object_or_404(Order, pk=pk)
    obj2 = Item.objects.filter(itemOrder=obj)
    obj3 = datetime.now()

    context = {"obj": obj, "obj2": obj2, "obj3": obj3}

    response = HttpResponse(content_type="application/pdf")
    response["Content-Disposition"] = 'filename="file.pdf"'
    template = get_template(template_path)
    html = template.render(context)

    
    pisa_status = pisa.CreatePDF(html.encode("UTF-8"), response , encoding='UTF-8', link_callback=link_callback)

    if pisa_status.err:
        return HttpResponse("We had some errors <pre>" + html + "</pre>")
    return response
```

**My settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ""),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
]
STATIC_ROOT = "static_root"

MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem @Tomasz? I am having the same issue and cannot find any answer.

Comment: Hi @Adrian, unfortunately I have not managed to finish this with xhtml2pdf. Initially my app was launched on Heroku, and I eventually used headless chrome to generate my pdf. To be specific, I used django-hardcopy and headless chrome buildpack on Heroku. Since heroku acounced cancelling free tier, my app has been migrated to another server and pdf is currently generated with wkhtmltopdf. If you do find a solution, please share, I remeber trying to work on it from different angles, however with no success.